# How to convert the received and replied email into text file

Tags: python, email, imap

I am writing a code to convert my received and replied mails into a single text file for a particular email ID using IMAP, but the problem is it is printing only the received emails not the reply emails I sent during that conversation, How to code this?

I expect my code to perform, "A text file that contains the received emails and their respective reply email in a form of conversation"

Comment: use https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools